# cannot set innerHTML property of null on Qualtrics

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, qualtrics

I am using Qualtrics to make a survey, and I need to do a bit of JS to make a timer. Unfortunately, I'm constantly running into "cannot set innerHTML property of null" for element "s5".

I've read the other thread about this issue (albeit the OP doesn't seem to be using qualtrics), and thought that perhaps changing "Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload" to "Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addReady" might do the trick, but it doesn't, and I've already tried changing the id's quite a few times to no avail. Could someone help me find where my error is?

I got marked previously for the same question (as something that's already been answered), but that thread didn't help me at all. I've tried ready() as shown in the commented out section in the first code snippet, but that only gave me a "startThinkingTimer is not defined" error. When I tried it the second way in the second code snippet, I didn't get any errors, but my timer wasn't visible/working at all either. I can't move script or use defer b/c Qualtrics does not have all the HTML/CSS/JS in one file, but has different sections for them and honestly I'm not sure how they connect the different files. Regarding using .on(), I'm not sure which event to use here, and would really like some help.

I've tried replacing all the document.getElementById for element "s5" with something like this:

```
$("s5").innerHTML="10";
```

but this doesn't work, either.

(Should I try to move the html code inside the JS portion (esp. the div timeShower part)? I'm not too sure how to do that though, so if someone could help me do that, that'd be awesome.)

```js
window.thinkingTimer_;
window.typingTimer_;

Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function(){
    that = this;
    
    var thinkingTimeLimit = 15;
    var typingTimeLimit = 10;
    
    jQuery(".InputText").hide();
    $('NextButton').hide();
    
    document.getElementById("instructions5").innerHTML = "You have 15 seconds to think about the prompt and come up with your two most favourite fruits, either from the list or from your previous choices. Textboxes will appear when the time is up.";

      function startTypingTimer() {
          that.enableNextButton();
          typingTimer_ = setInterval( function(){
              if (typingTimeLimit > 0) {
                  document.getElementById("s5").innerHTML=pad(--typingTimeLimit%60);
                  document.getElementById("minutes5").innerHTML=pad(parseInt(typingTimeLimit/60,10));
              }
              if (typingTimeLimit == 0) {
                  clearInterval(typingTimer_);
                  jQuery("#NextButton").click();
              }
            }, 1000);
      }
    
    /*
    $(function startThinkingTimer() {
                  that.disableNextButton();
                  thinkingTimer_ = setInterval( function(){
                      if (thinkingTimeLimit >0) {
                          document.getElementById("s5").innerHTML=pad(--thinkingTimeLimit%60);
                          document.getElementById("minutes5").innerHTML=pad(parseInt(thinkingTimeLimit/60,10));
                      }
                      if (thinkingTimeLimit == 0) {
                          clearInterval(thinkingTimer_);
                          document.getElementById("s5").innerHTML="10";
                          document.getElementById("minutes5").innerHTML="00";
                          jQuery(".InputText").show();
                          document.getElementById("instructions5").innerHTML = "You now have 10 seconds to type in the two fruits. The page will automatically move on to the next page once time is up.";
                          startTypingTimer();
                      }
                    }, 1000);
              });
    */
    
      function startThinkingTimer() {
            that.disableNextButton();
          thinkingTimer_ = setInterval( function(){
              if (thinkingTimeLimit >0) {
                  document.getElementById("s5").innerHTML=pad(--thinkingTimeLimit%60);
                  document.getElementById("minutes5").innerHTML=pad(parseInt(thinkingTimeLimit/60,10));
              }
              if (thinkingTimeLimit == 0) {
                  clearInterval(thinkingTimer_);
                  document.getElementById("s5").innerHTML="10";
                  document.getElementById("minutes5").innerHTML="00";
                  jQuery(".InputText").show();
                  document.getElementById("instructions5").innerHTML = "You now have 10 seconds to type in the two fruits. The page will automatically move on to the next page once time is up.";
                  startTypingTimer();
              }
            }, 1000);
      }
    
    function pad (val) { 
        return val > 9 ? val : "0" + val; 
    }
    
    startThinkingTimer();    

});
```

```html
<div id="instructions5">&nbsp;</div>

<div id="timeShower1">time: <span id="minutes5">00</span>:<span id="s5">15</span></div>
```

```js
window.thinkingTimer_;
window.typingTimer_;

Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function(){

    that = this;
    
    var thinkingTimeLimit = 15;
    var typingTimeLimit = 10;
    
    jQuery(".InputText").hide();
    $('NextButton').hide();
    
    document.getElementById("instructions5").innerHTML = "You have 15 seconds to think about the prompt and come up with your two most favourite fruits, either from the list or from your previous choices. Textboxes will appear when the time is up.";

      function startTypingTimer() {
          that.enableNextButton();
          typingTimer_ = setInterval( function(){
              if (typingTimeLimit > 0) {
                  document.getElementById("s5").innerHTML=pad(--typingTimeLimit%60);
                  document.getElementById("minutes5").innerHTML=pad(parseInt(typingTimeLimit/60,10));
              }
              if (typingTimeLimit == 0) {
                  clearInterval(typingTimer_);
                  jQuery("#NextButton").click();
              }
            }, 1000);
      }
    
    
      $(function () {
          that.disableNextButton();
          thinkingTimer_ = setInterval( function(){
              if (thinkingTimeLimit >0) {
                  document.getElementById("s5").innerHTML=pad(--thinkingTimeLimit%60);
                  document.getElementById("minutes5").innerHTML=pad(parseInt(thinkingTimeLimit/60,10));
              }
              if (thinkingTimeLimit == 0) {
                  clearInterval(thinkingTimer_);
                  document.getElementById("s5").innerHTML="10";
                  document.getElementById("minutes5").innerHTML="00";
                  jQuery(".InputText").show();
                  document.getElementById("instructions5").innerHTML = "You now have 10 seconds to type in the two fruits. The page will automatically move on to the next page once time is up.";
                  startTypingTimer();
              }
            }, 1000);
      });
     
    /*
    function startThinkingTimer() {
          that.disableNextButton();
          thinkingTimer_ = setInterval( function(){
              if (thinkingTimeLimit >0) {
                  document.getElementById("s5").innerHTML=pad(--thinkingTimeLimit%60);
                  document.getElementById("minutes5").innerHTML=pad(parseInt(thinkingTimeLimit/60,10));
              }
              if (thinkingTimeLimit == 0) {
                  clearInterval(thinkingTimer_);
                  document.getElementById("s5").innerHTML="10";
                  document.getElementById("minutes5").innerHTML="00";
                  jQuery(".InputText").show();
                  document.getElementById("instructions5").innerHTML = "You now have 10 seconds to type in the two fruits. The page will automatically move on to the next page once time is up.";
                  startTypingTimer();
              }
            }, 1000);
      }*/
    
    function pad (val) { 
        return val > 9 ? val : "0" + val; 
    }
    
    //startThinkingTimer();    
    
});
```

Comment: `document.getElementById('foo')` in jQuery is `$('#foo')` . Your code inconsistently uses `$('NextButton').hide()` and some lines later `jQuery("#NextButton").click();`. This makes the impression you don't know what you're doing?!

Comment: @connexo to be honest, I'm very new to javascript. Is what I'm doing very wrong? I thought those were all right since the code used to work...

Comment: also, what's the difference between doing jQuery("#NextButton") and $("#NextButton")? I get the impression they're different.

Comment: Can you create a working snippet (the snippets in the questions are not working)? It will be much eaiser for us to help you thi way.

Comment: @norwegian_forest - $ in Qualtrics is an alias for prototypejs, so $ and jQuery are different. Hence the need to type out jQuery.

Comment: @MoshFeu qualtrics has a bunch of code so that it's difficult to give a working snippet here. would you be willing to look at it if I made a video of what my problem is?

Comment: It could be nice since we usually need to "play" with the code, it's not optimal. Is your site public? Can we access it?